# Info-Path buttons grey out or hide automatically when not needed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, infopath, infopath-rules

I created a infopath form that is divided into views and put some buttons to switch the views.  I want the last two buttons will only work during a month of August and December. And rest of the time, the buttons will grey out or hide automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden field.
write down default value as `=TEXT([DateField];"mmm")`

On Button add formatting condition as Not equal to "AUG" OR Not equal to "DEC" then hide.